# add a ul dynamically after all the input elements in a div

Tags: jquery, css

I need to add a ul after all the input elements of a div using jquery. 
This is typically validating a phone number. So if any of the above phone text box validation fails, all the phone text boxes needs to be highlighted in red and then I need to display the error message after all the inputs. The error message I am dynamically adding using jquery.

```
<div class="class1">
   <input class="class2" type="text" id="id1" name="id1" maxlength="3" title="Please enter value"/>
   <span class="class3">-</span>
   <input class="class2" type="text" id="id2" name="id2" title="Please enter value"/>
   <span class="class3">-</span>
   <input class="class2 " type="text" id="id3" name="id3" title="Please enter value"/>
   <span class="class3">Ext.</span>
   <input class="class2" type="text" id="id4" name="id4" />
   <input type="hidden" id="hidden_id" />
  <!--Need to add ul element here-->
</div>
```

JS function

```
$(function() {

function validate(){
var returnVal = true;
var input = $('#id1');
input.nextAll("ul.error").remove();
input.removeClass('wrong');
input.removeClass('correct');
if(input.val() == 0)
{    
    input.addClass('wrong');
    var title = input.attr('title');
    $('<ul class="error"><li>'+title+'</li></ul>').insertAfter(input.nextAll("input"));
    return false;
}
else{
    input.addClass('correct');
    returnVal = true;
}
return returnVal;
}

('#subBtn').click(function(){
   var retVal = validate();
   });

$('#id1').blur(validate);

});
```

If I am using the below code for inserting the error, the error is displayed after all the input text boxes.

```
$('<ul class="error"><li>'+title+'</li></ul>').insertAfter(input.nextAll("input"));
```

I need to display only one error message which needs to be displayed after the last input and also if the input is correct i need to remove the "wrong" class and add "correct" class
How can I do that?
Can somebody help me?

Thanks

Comment: Why use a `ul` with a single `li` in it for the validation message? Wouldn't a `label` or `span` be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the last sibling input, try:

```
//for id1, input.siblings('input').last() will be the hidden_id

$('<ul class="error"><li>'+title+'</li></ul>').insertAfter(input.siblings('input').last())
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using UL use two divs with classes different for error and correct. So based on your logic you can use something like this:

```
if error ($("#divError").html("Some error msg");)
else $("#divCorrect").html("Some success msg");
```

where divError and divCorrect are div ids like this:

```
<div id='divError' class='error'></div>
<div id='divCorrect' class='correct'></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi SAndip..Thanks for ur reply..This is the format the code has been written..Actually they have written ul elements in the html itself..I am trying to remove those and add it dynamically..

Comment: Writing ULs dynamically is fine as it is your requirement, just add a div with the class u want to assign it and keep it empty. Using jquery u set content to that div

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$('<ul class="error"><li>'+title+'</li></ul>').insertAfter(input.last());`

I think this will insert the `ul` after the last input element.